# How to performantely reject simultanous requests (PHP based API)

Tags: php

While I have some ideas (IPC, using mysql heap table, memory cache) none of my ideas seem to be working "perfectly".

I look for a way to block any simultanous access to the PHP script from the same user.
All users accessing my script supply a User-ID on every call, so I know who is knocking the door before I open it.
However, it can happen that users "spam" the hell out of my API, I do not want that anyone can access the script while a previous "api call" is unfinished.

I need something with low system impact and without any race-conditions (flawless handling even if requests come in within a millisecond or faster).

I'd be glad for suggestions or info how you solved a similar issue.

Platform is Linux.

Update:
I rejected using a database so far because I fear that sending thousands of update or similar queries per second could stall the server even if the single impact is low.
Sometimes the users tool accessing my API is faulty and just bombards it with massive queries, I expect that to be a performance hit if it's handled through my DB.

Comment: This is my think, I'm not sure it's right.  You can create an access_token and set a lifetime. If they want to use your API, they should apply an access_token.

Comment: If you have a database - you can use pessimistic locking mechanism it provides.

Comment: Considered a database but I think it's among the most "heavy" solutions I think.
I could "update" which is atomic and then check if it worked.
I don't like the idea of blasting my database connection with potentially thousands of additional "update" per second if someones script is going crazy

Comment: The throughput requirements will vary the answer on this one by a large factor. Are we talking about dozens of requests a second or tens of thousands?

Comment: usually dozends but sometimes software plays bad so it can go to multiple hundreds / sec in such a case.

Answer (score 3):

If I were in your situation, I'd probably start with Redis.  Redis is pretty darned performant, and is likely good enough.

In particular, I'd be looking at the [SETNX](http://redis.io/commands/setnx) command.  And I'd look at making the key expire after a short while (so if your PHP code dies and doesn't DEL the key, your customer isn't locked out indefinitely).

Once I had something like that working, and convinced myself it would perform well enough, I'd follow the suggestion on the above-linked page, and look into [distributed locks](http://redis.io/topics/distlock).

Comment: I like that db, looks really cool.
But not sure if I want to add another dependency to the system. 
I was hoping for a nice solution that doesn't require additional packages.
However, Redis looks neat

Comment: Redis is a pretty light dependency, and has huge utility.  If you don't want to add a dependency, you can try to write lock-files to disk, but it gets complicated quickly with potential for race-conditions, is probably slow, and doesn't scale beyond a single box.  These days, I pretty much always assume a redis dependency, since it's useful for so many things (it's a cache! it's a queue! you can do a mutex! etc...)